# Conditional actions in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

I have a panda dataframe and I want to set the value in one column based on the value in another column. There are 6 possible scenarios so a single if/else won't work. I can't get the combination of If/else to work with the scenarios where SBT is >=x and <=y.
The following is from an iterative macro in my Excel VBA code that I am trying to recreated in Python. It moves down each row making a check. I know it can be much more efficient in Python.

```
If SBT > 3.6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "2"
ElseIf SBT >= 2.95 And SBT <= 3.6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "3"
ElseIf SBT >= 2.6 And SBT <= 2.95 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "4"
ElseIf SBT >= 2.05 And SBT <= 2.6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "5"
ElseIf SBT >= 1.31 And SBT <= 2.05 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "6"
ElseIf SBT < 1.31 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "7"
Else
End If
```

I have looked at

```
np.where(a < 4, -1, 100)
```

and

```
df['desired_output'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: 'true' if x <= 2.5 else 'false')
```

Are either of these viable options? How do I go about nesting the statements (particularly the 'between these values' parts, or is there another more efficient way of doing this?
A snippet of the data below (SBT) and the expected result (SBTno).

```
SBT   SBTn
7.00    2
1.28    7
3.64    2
2.97    3
2.83    4
```

Comment: .apply() with lambda has it's limitation, have you think about make a function then use it with .apply()?

Comment: I'm very new to this, what would the function look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way from `cut`

```
s=pd.cut(df.SBT,bins=[0,1.31,2.05,2.6,2.95,3.6,np.Inf],labels=[7,6,5,4,3,2])
0    2
1    7
2    2
3    3
4    4
df['SBTn']=s.astype(str)
```

Comment: nice answer & name change (:

Comment: @Datanovice ah yes :-)

Comment: This worked well, I thought, but has caused problems further down the line. On one row, the maths has created a NaN output. I assume because of the (str) designation, it comes out as nan and can't be found by a fillna or np.nan type replacement.

Comment: The graph of SBTNn against Depth also looks wrong as it is sequentially ordering the SBTNn values rather than numerically ordering them.  I tried to set the =s.astype to (int) but get an error message because of the np.Inf

Comment: OK, ignore my last, I can convert them using pd.to_numeric

Comment: @AtlanticWorker ah ok , also you need to know the max and min of your data range , so that can determine the bins boundary

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to write the logic in a function and use apply

```
def create_desired_output(SBT):
    if SBT > 3.6:
        return 2
    if SBT >= 2.95 and SBT <= 3.6:
        return 3
    if SBT >= 2.6 and SBT <= 2.95:
        return 4
    if SBT >= 2.05 and SBT <= 2.6:
        return 5
    if SBT >= 1.31 and SBT <= 2.05:
        return 6
    if SBT < 1.31:
        return 7
    return ''
df['desired_output'] = df['SBT'].apply(lambda x: create_desired_output(x))
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this setup which doesn't go against pandas core functionality by using a python for loop :

using numpy :

```
import numpy as np
col         = 'SBT'
conditions  = [ df[col] > 3.4, (df[col] > 2.95) & (df[col] <= 3.6)] 
choices     = [ 2, 3]
df2["desired_output"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan) 
# adding NaN for anything that doesn't meet the condition
```

conditions has your logical inputs, imagine writing your if,else statements without the outputs.

then choices is the output when those conditions are met in the same order as your conditions.

you can then use `np.select` to initlaise the logic on your dataframe.

if your actual logic matches your sample input then using @YO and BEN_W answer is best, if you have `if/else` type logic then try the above.

if you wanted to nest `np.where`

you could do something like this would get very long tho so i'd only recommend for shorter conditions.

```
np.where(x > 1, -1,
                  (np.where(x < 1, 0,
                                     (np.where(x...
```